# Move forward over a compound statement in emacs

Tags: c, emacs

Is there an emacs command to move forward over a compound statement in C or C++ files?

If I have the following code

```
^ if (foo)
{
   doSomething();
}$
```

and the point is at the caret (`^`), I want to be able to do something like `M-x forward-compound-statement RET` and have the point move to the dollar sign.

`forward-sexp` seems like it should be the right command, but that will only step over a single word, putting the point after the if.  `c-end-of-statement` is also wrong, as it only goes to the first close parenthesis.

EDIT: In the case of an if-then-else-if-else block, I would ideally want it to go past all of the else blocks.

I am also hoping to use this inside defuns that I write in the future, so key strokes are less of a concern than having one command to do it rather than repeating a command until I see that it gets to the right location.

Comment: Are `forward-list` and `backward-list` closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: `forward-sexp` will jump from `{` to `}` when mark is at `{`.

Comment: @wvxvw Good question about the else statement.  In the specific case I was thinking of, there is no else.  In general, I think that I want it to go to the next place you could insert a semicolon and not change the code, so it would move past the else / else if blocks as well.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield It's closer.  In my example, it moves from the caret to after `foo`, which is still short of where I want it to go.

Comment: Yes, `forward-sexp` "should" be the right command.  But c-mode does not try to explain it how to jump over such statements.  Going back from the `$` to the `^` is tricker because `$` is at the end of both the `if` expression and the `{...}` block, so the request to `backward-sexp` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `forward-compound-statement` may very well exist for specific major-modes.  I wouldn't bother learning them though.

Instead, I recommend you get used to navigating with more composable commands like <kbd>C-s</kbd>.  You can try something like jump-char to shorten the sequence by one key.

Comment: I was going to recommend `ace-jump-mode` but if you lookup `jump-char` you will see that it is a recommendation for it.